# error creating new project using angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular5

I'm encountering error when creating new app using angular cli

I tried :

```
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
```

but it didn't work

please see image below

[image]

Logs:

```
2174 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ul-reporter","version'
2174 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
2174 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
2174 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
2174 verbose stack     at <anonymous>
2174 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
2175 verbose cwd C:\Users\nielcleoa\Desktop\appsample
2176 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
2177 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--quiet"
2178 verbose node v8.11.3
2179 verbose npm  v5.6.0
2180 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ul-reporter","version'
2181 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

versions used:

```
node version: 8.11.3 
npm version: 5.6.0 
angular-cli version: 6.0.8
```

Comment: What are your NPM, Node, angular-cli, etc versions?

Comment: node version: 8.11.3
npm version: 5.6.0
angular-cli version: 6.0.8

Comment: try upgrading to latest angular-cli version and then create a new project `npm i -g @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: I tried to update and still same error I get. But when I upgrade my angular-cli I got warning says that Skipping Optional Dependency: Unsupported platform for fsevent@1.2.4. I dont know if it has relation on my error.

Comment: Try updating to a newer version of npm (`npm install -g npm`) and see if that helps. BTW, the fsevent warning can be ignored since you are running Windows.

Comment: still I get the same error. Does windows 32bit matters when using angular-cli? since I'm running on a 32bit win os.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

Comment: got this error.. 1402 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...hint":"*","yui-lint":'
1402 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: when running `npm install -g angular-cli@latest`

Comment: Run as administrator cmd: npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to install the Angular2+ CLI?

If so this is the command:

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

The command from your comments above is the old AngularJS CLI, ie: `npm install -g angular-cli`.

Docs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli

Comment: Do you have both CLI packages installed on your machine?

Comment: Can you share what your angular.json file looks like? It looks like this generated the appropriate files, but failed when installing packages.

Comment: And your package.json? I have read instances where commented out lines in these files can cause issues

Comment: here's my angular.json http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=40808711686772554829 and package json http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=79350791446681310260

Comment: I don't see anything out of the ordinary there. Have you tried just rerunning `npm install` or `ng serve` in the root of your project folder again?

Comment: just finsihed right now i got new error when using npm install then when running ng serve got this message please see uploaded image https://imgur.com/a/2RRlYTL

Comment: Ok can you try this: delete entire node_module folder, delete package-lock.json (not package.json), run `npm cache verify`, then run `npm install`. Let me know any errors you get there if any.

Comment: The most recent error or the original error from your post? I am at a bit of a loss here now, these are the steps I usually take to clear up npm issues with angular

Comment: got the recent error.. I don't see package-lock.json on my project folder.. also the content of my node_modules is only .staging folder..

Comment: I think you're in some sort of npm issue unrelated to angular. My suggestion would be a fresh npm/node install to make sure. Outside of that I haven't experienced this ever.

Comment: I should try to reinstall my node.. already send issue to npm regarding on my error. Thanks mate for helping!